# PG CONNECTION TIME OUT ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am frequently getting Pg Connection timeout error in my application. I tried to fix it by upgrading the system memory, also updated the pg gem but the issue is still occurring. Anybody's help will be really appreciated.

> (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) "PGError: server closed the
>   connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated
>   abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request.\n: BEGIN"

Comment: what do you postgres server logs say?  Anything there?

Comment: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out

Comment: same box? different box? what is connectivity between clients like? when connection dies is it only on 1 or is there all? any connection pooling going on?

Comment: Your application is on the same host as the `PostgreSQL` server ?

Comment: 'Frequently getting' means that it works some of the time, but you get these errors sporadically?  Or does it not work at all?

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here. PostgreSQL version? Host and client OS? How are the two connected to each other? What software firewall(s) are involved? Routers and other network topology details? Is there NAT?

Answer (score 1):

Both the client and server think that the other vanished unexpectedly. This suggests that you're having networking problems. Look into the network between client and server:

- NAT routers or connection-tracking stateful firewalls with short-lived or undersized connection tables;
- Physical connectivity problems with cables, WiFi, etc
- Faulty switches, hubs and routers
- Buggy software host-based firewalls
- ... etc

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the easiest solution is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!` once connectivity is re-established.

Comment: In my case since I was using `establish_connection` inside my model I use `ModelName.connection.reconnect!`. Thankyou for this @jack .